# Sampling from forecasting interval

Tags: forecasting, sampling, arima, prediction, prediction-interval

Suppose I have an ARIMA model with $n$ step ahead forecasts and forecast intervals. If I want to sample from those forecasts:

- One way to look at is: take one observation from the prediction distribution in each step, then you have one path. Repeat this process.
- But when you choose your first observation from the first prediction distribution, the second observation is dependent on the first one, isn't it?

Any insights?

Comment: Yes, you are right. And of course we *want* this dependence. If your time series were independent, there would not be a point to time series modeling. Does this answer your question, or could you clarify if something is still unclear to you?

Comment: What is the exact question here? Also note that ARIMA is an acronym, so we do not use formula formatting for it, we just use capital letters.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, yes it does. It seems that *simulate* function in *forecast* package in *R* does the job for sampling from the forecasts. This [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115710/difference-between-the-forecast-and-simulate-functions-in-the-forecast-package) is useful.